# Win32Dasm folating-point operation error

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly

Recently I tried to do some jobs as old days using Win32Dasm v8.93 but getting a strange folating-point operation error.

[image]

since last successful usage of this tool for me backs to XP days and already had a Windows XP virtual machine so tried it there but still get the same error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32Dasm won't support instructions used by modern compilers when generating code. See a [list of floating-point extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions#Later_versions) that have been added since Win32Dasm was released.

I'd suggest moving to a modern debugger, such as [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/), which supports the new instructions and also the 64-bit architecture.